# iOS Parse notification with custom radius geopoint from key

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a huge problem with Parse for iOS and geo-query for push notifications.
What I want to do schematically.
class "helpLocationListener"

| Location | radius | user |

| Xxx | 2 | userA |

| Xxy | 5 | userB |

| Xyy | 2.5 | userC |

When a user sends a "help" geo-located, other users should be notified ONLY IF the "help" is within the area to be calculated | location | and | radius |
If the coordinates of the "help" are contained in the area date from XXX with radius 2, the user userA will receive a push notification.

Absurdly I would need something that does this:
userQuery.whereKey ("location", nearGeoPoint: "help", withinMiles "***radius***")

I searched for hours but could not find any answer, if this is not possible my application would not make sense to exist. Similarly it seems impossible that this possibility has not been provided.

*I'm using Swift lang.*

I ask you a sincere help! (Sorry for my english)

Comment: Wouldn't using the distance they are apart, as in `withinMiles` create a radius by default? Anything returned by that query would only return points within that distance, essentially creating a radius.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Can you give me an example? I hope that the concept of what the query has to do is understandable.
When a user enters a "help" with a geographic location, I have to send a notification to all users who have chosen to "monitor" a specific area for which they have previously chosen a point and a radius stored in a class (ex. "listeningAreas ")

Comment: Miles is a distance, right? So when you set the distance, `withinMiles` on your `PFQuery` from your "listeningAreas" class, the distance that the query gets set with basically provides a radius. If the user chose 2 miles as their distance and that's stored in "listeningAreas" and you construct the query where `withinMiles` is the distance they've choosen, the query will only return results within that distance, and that's two miles in any direction, which creates a radius just as you've described you need.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you said. But the "radius" must be taken from each class containing a listening area.It is different for each user (and for each listening area) and in the query can not use a key but I should use an integer. That is the question. I do not care if I have to use "withinMiles" or another command, I care about the result. Basically it is just the opposite of an application where the user notifies other users nearby. I must notify the event to users who have chosen to monitor an area determined by a point and a radius.
If you know how to do it, can give me an example code?

Comment: I mean: the user sending the "help", then the GEOPOINT, saves it to the class "helps". It provides no radius. other users who have chosen an area to be monitored (GEOPOINT + radius) must be notified ONLY IF help's geopoint is contained in the area. I do not know where to look! in entire web there are 2-3 similar questions but no answers!

Comment: Visual example: [CLICK FOR VIEW IMAGE](http://i58.tinypic.com/xf9b2a.png)